# Contour plot coloured by clustering of points matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors which are paired values

```
size(X)=1e4 x 1; size(Y)=1e4 x 1
```

Is it possible to plot a `contour plot` of some sort making the contours by the highest density of points?  Ie highest clustering=red, and then gradient colour elsewhere?

If you need more clarification please ask.
Regards,

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
X=[53 58 62 56 72 63 65 57 52 56 52 70 54 54 59 58 71 66 55 56];  
Y=[40 33 35 37 33 36 32 36 35 33 41 35 37 31 40 41 34 33 34 37 ];
 scatter(X,Y,'ro');
```

[image]

Thank you for everyone's help.  Also remembered we can use `hist3`:

```
x={0:0.38/4:0.38}; % # How many bins in x direction
y={0:0.65/7:0.65}; % # How many bins in y direction

ncount=hist3([X Y],'Edges',[x y]);
pcolor(ncount./sum(sum(ncount)));
colorbar
```

Anyone know why `edges` in hist3 have to be cells?

Comment: I need more clarification. If you could draw some images and post some example data(Or a way to create it), it would be great.

Comment: @Andrey Here is a sample scatter plot. What I'm looking for is a contour of high to low density of point clustering.  I believe it is also possible to find the centroid of this data too.  What do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is basically a question about estimating the probability density function generating your data and then visualizing it in a good and meaningful way I'd say. To that end, I would recommend using a more smooth estimate than the histogram, for instance Parzen windowing (a generalization of the histogram method).

In my code below, I have used your example dataset, and estimated the probability density in a grid set up by the range of your data. You here have 3 variables you need to adjust to use on your original data; Borders, Sigma and stepSize.

```
Border = 5;
Sigma = 5;
stepSize = 1;

X=[53 58 62 56 72 63 65 57 52 56 52 70 54 54 59 58 71 66 55 56];  
Y=[40 33 35 37 33 36 32 36 35 33 41 35 37 31 40 41 34 33 34 37 ];
D = [X' Y'];
N = length(X);


Xrange = [min(X)-Border max(X)+Border];
Yrange = [min(Y)-Border max(Y)+Border];


%Setup coordinate grid
[XX YY] = meshgrid(Xrange(1):stepSize:Xrange(2), Yrange(1):stepSize:Yrange(2));
YY = flipud(YY);

%Parzen parameters and function handle
pf1 = @(C1,C2) (1/N)*(1/((2*pi)*Sigma^2)).*...
         exp(-( (C1(1)-C2(1))^2+ (C1(2)-C2(2))^2)/(2*Sigma^2));

PPDF1 = zeros(size(XX));    

%Populate coordinate surface
[R C] = size(PPDF1);
NN = length(D);
for c=1:C
   for r=1:R 
       for d=1:N 
            PPDF1(r,c) = PPDF1(r,c) + ...
                pf1([XX(1,c) YY(r,1)],[D(d,1) D(d,2)]); 
       end
   end
end


%Normalize data
m1 = max(PPDF1(:));
PPDF1 = PPDF1 / m1;

%Set up visualization
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex','DefaultAxesFontSize',20)
fig = figure(1);clf
stem3(D(:,1),D(:,2),zeros(N,1),'b.');
hold on;

%Add PDF estimates to figure
s1 = surfc(XX,YY,PPDF1);shading interp;alpha(s1,'color');
sub1=gca;
view(2)
axis([Xrange(1) Xrange(2) Yrange(1) Yrange(2)])
```

[image]

Note, this visualization is actually 3-dimensional:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I was looking for, especially as my data has strictly only one global maximum. I need to look at this thoroughly in detail.  It occurs to me though, that in cases where data is sparse or containing multiple 'peak', how well does it deal with these phenomena?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. This method is highly dependent on which Sigma you chose to use for your data. If its properly selected (not too high and not too small), the method should return a usable estimate. If Sigma is too small, you'll see small bumps around all your datapoints; if its too big, the estimate will become too coarse and not extract all of the information. Keep in mind that all these estimation methods require a good amount of data to work correctly, and the estimate is only valid in the regions populated by data points.

Comment: Is there a rigorous method to choose your sigma value (based on the data variation perhaps?)? What happens though when data is clearly bimodal. Can it capture the trough between the peaks?  I'll try this out and see what happens.

Comment: There's no exactly rigorous method of choosing sigma, but you could look up 'Silverman's rule of thumb' which is very commonly used, at least for 2 dimensional data. It should be able to detect the valley between the peaks. Do you have label information to go on if you have a two class case?

Comment: Yes I know which classes my data vectors come from. Although in the one dimensional case is this this method a good predictor of class?

Comment: Yes it should be suited for predicting the class of a new data point regardless of the dimensionality - given that your Sigma is chosen so that the underlying probability structure is uncovered.

Answer (score 2):

See this 4 minute video on the mathworks site:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/01/22/advanced-making-a-2d-or-3d-histogram-to-visualize-data-density/

I believe this should provide very close to exactly the functionality you require.

Comment: on SO people usually explain what the content of the link is, in case it becomes unavailable at a later date... fortunately it still is available after almost 10 years... =)

Answer (score 1):

I would divide the area the plot covers into a grid and then count the number of points in each square of the grid. Here's an example of how that could be done.

```
% Get random data with high density
X=randn(1e4,1);
Y=randn(1e4,1);

Xmin=min(X);
Xmax=max(X);
Ymin=min(Y);
Ymax=max(Y);
% guess of grid size, could be divided into nx and ny
n=floor((length(X))^0.25); 

% Create x and y-axis
x=linspace(Xmin,Xmax,n);
y=linspace(Ymin,Ymax,n);
dx=x(2)-x(1);
dy=y(2)-y(1);
griddata=zeros(n);
for i=1:length(X)
    % Calculate which bin the point is positioned in
    indexX=floor((X(i)-Xmin)/dx)+1;
    indexY=floor((Y(i)-Ymin)/dy)+1;
    griddata(indexX,indexY)=griddata(indexX,indexY)+1;
end
contourf(x,y,griddata)
```

Edit: The video in the answer by Marm0t uses the same technique but probably explains it in a better way.