# MATLAB Plotting Contour Map from Different Plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour

I am trying to write a MATLAB script to give me a contour map. The contour map must be created from inputs that I generated from 100 images.

The story is like this:

I have 100 images on which I ran an image processing algorithm for optimization. Now, I got their energy curves. So, I have 100 energy curves. I want to create a contour map that will show me where the points are denser on the plot. (the energy curves are plotted as energy vs. iteration with fixed number of iterations)

The following is my variable:

```
energy(iteration,numImages)
```

[image: This is the image showing 100 energy curves plotted on the same figure]

Hope I explained it well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you post what you've already tried? This will allow you to get better help!

Comment: I have tried adding 1 for every point each curve is passing through. But I couldn't get that code to work and I couldn't translate it onto a 3d map.

Comment: You can create a kind of heatmap no ? For example with `imagesc`.

Comment: Heatmap would also work. However, I have to sum all values to do that. I couldn't sum the values in a good way to help me use imagesc.

Comment: 1) use `semilogy` 2) do not plot the energy , plot the energy divided by the energy of the data, so the maximum value is 1 (thus your plot doesn't have arbitrary units)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did those. Can you also please give me an insight about how I can generate the contour plot?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-scattered-data.html
I have tried some parts of this link and still can't get my code to work.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see of you graph (and using the comments also), one possible way is to use plot3 to plot a line in 3D for every plot.

For doing so, you can use something like this code:

```
x=(0:0.01:1)';

aexp=zeros(100,numel(x));
hold on
for ii=1:100;
%      aexp(ii,:)=exp((-x+ii/10)); %exponential
     aexp(ii,:)=exp(-(x-ii/100).^2); %~gaussian
%     aexp(ii,:)= x*ii; %linear increase 
    plot3(x,aexp(ii,:),ii*ones(1,numel(x)));
end
 % set(gca,'yscale','log'); % uncomment if you need logscale.
```

giving
[image: plot3 plot]
I have a few options of plot. It always plot from the XY view. I changed by hand, but you can use the [view command](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html). Notice that i used a simple counter to make the spacing in the *z* direction.

In a similar manner, you can plot using the *contour*. For my code, after the data have been generated in the for loop, remove/comment the plot3  and add:

```
contour(aexp) %outside the for loop,
```

giving
[image: Contour plot]

Notice that i have not really take care what i'm plotting. You can find more info on contour in the [Matlab page](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) .

You commented that the x-axis should be number of iterations, y-axis should be energy and z-axis should be the information containing how many lines are passing through from some areas.  For this, make a `qq` variable, being it `qq=number_of_lines(number of iterations,energy)` . Make a discrete grid for the energy if you don't have one. Number of iterations is probably discrete anyway. The function is you who need to devise, but i would go for something which checks the number of lines for every energy and every iteration. In this case you will have the z-function that depends on y and x, that is the case to use contour or surface.

My function above make a line for every `ii` point, to have a 3d function. An edition for another extra loop is not hard. Just remember to have the same regular grid for every point, otherwise you will have trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case the x-axis should be `number of iterations`, y-axis should be `energy` and z-axis should be the information containing how many lines are passing through from some areas. It should show the density of the lines as contour. If you may suggest anything more under the light of this new information I really would appriciate that.

Comment: I edited the question. Check the last 2 parts. Not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134014/contour-plot-coloured-by-clustering-of-points-matlab

This link actually describes my problem very well. In this the variables X and Y are just vectors. I am trying to modify this bit of code to suit my needs. Maybe if you can also look at this, you can give me another point of view.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually the function makes pretty much what i described in the latest part -- a z-function of x and y -- the but in a way more elegant (both mathematically and visually) manner with the actual code :D .  
I would follow that code, but as you are interested in the "lines per area", take care to do not make a mistake with the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question to boil down to how can I create a surface plot with colors according to the energy found in `energy`.  I would solve this by using the `contour` function with a grid generated using `meshgrid`.  If each image is described in 1000 data points with 100 files the plot can be generated as follows:

```
% using stuff as random junk instead of energy
numPoints = 1000;
numFiles = 100;
stuff = rand(1000,100); % replace with actual information
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:numFiles, 1:numPoints);
contour(X,Y,stuff);
```

You can also create a 3D surface plot using `surf` and the same logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case the x-axis should be number of iterations, y-axis should be energy and z-axis should be the information containing how many lines are passing through from some areas. It should show the density of the lines as contour. I have tried a similar thing to your code and tried adding 1 to each point each line is passing through instead of `stuff` but I was unsuccessful in doing so.